# Hiding active language in menu

Tags: php, jquery, hide

I think that my "problem" is quite easy to solve, but I really can't, even if I tried and searched a lot... so, this is the question. I just want to hide from my dropdown menu the active language. This is my code:

```
 <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><?php echo $lang['LINGUA']; ?></a>
  <ul>
 <li><a href="index.php?lang=it"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/it.png" alt="Italiano"> Italiano</a>

<li><a  href="index.php?lang=fr"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/fr.png" alt="Francais"> Fran&ccedil;ais</a></li>

 <li><a href="index.php?lang=en"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/en.png" alt="English"> English</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
```

When I click on the first `<li>`, I select the language I want from the dropdown. Then, the selected language is the only one I see, the active one. But in the dropdown I can still see that active language, while it should be hidden from the dropdown.

I hope the question is clear.
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$lang['LINGUA']` is the active lang and the value of this $var is like 'EN', 'FR', 'IT', ...

```
<?php   if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'IT') { // if lang is not IT we display this line ?>
<li><a href="index.php?lang=it"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/it.png" alt="Italiano"> Italiano</a>
<?php } if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'FR') { // if lang is not FR we display this line ?>
<li><a href="index.php?lang=fr"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/fr.png" alt="Francais"> Fran&ccedil;ais</a></li>
<?php } if($lang['LINGUA'] != 'EN') { // if lang is not EN we display this line ?>
<li><a href="index.php?lang=en"><img class="iclflag" src="assets/images/flags/en.png" alt="English"> English</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use session or cookie : `$_session['ActiveLanguage']='IT';`
and in js

```
var hidelang=<?=$_session['ActiveLanguage'];?>
$(a[href*='lang='+hidelang]).hide();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried your solutions but I can't really understand how to implement that code into mine...